# Why does Google Optimize not load via Google Analytics 'require'?

Tags: google-analytics, google-optimize

I've followed these instructions to load the Google Optimize snippet via Google Analytics: https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6262084

It basically comes down to one new line in my GA code:

```
ga('require', 'GTM-S1O2M3E');
```

The whole GA snippet looks like this (I've added line breaks for readability):

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments);
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o);
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('require', 'GTM-S1O2M3E');
ga('create', 'UA-NNNNNNNN-N', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

When I run a preview of my Optimize experiment, the Google Optimize Chrome extension complains after a few seconds with this alert:

```
The Google Optimize snippet for the container with ID GTM-S1O2M3E is not correctly installed on this page.
To preview experiences or debug the container, make sure the Google Optimize snippet is installed on any pages
you want to test.
```

Inspecting the Network tab in the Developer Tools, I cannot find any request that contains my OPT_CONTAINER_ID - it looks like GA never loads it! Also, checking for the global variable `google_optimize` returns undefined (I found that here: https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/9059383?hl=en).

BUT when I execute the line `ga('require', 'GTM-S1O2M3E');` in the Developer Tools console manually, I see both a **new request** happening **and** the `google_optimize` **variable** being instantiated!

So WHY does GA not load the Optimize script in the beginning, as it should?

Comment: Just want to double check, are you using analytics.js or gtag.js or GTM?

Comment: Thanks for checking - we use analytics.js, that's also why I pointed to the article "Install Optimize using analytics.js".

Comment: would you mind posting the whole GA snippet? you can remove the property ID if you like.

Comment: I don't mind :-)

Comment: I've updated the question with the full GA snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reversing the following lines of code

From:

```
ga('require', 'GTM-S1O2M3E');
ga('create', 'UA-NNNNNNNN-N', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

To:

```
ga('create', 'UA-NNNNNNNN-N', 'auto');
ga('require', 'GTM-S1O2M3E');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: This was it. I've found this solution three days ago, too :-D Thanks for posting your answer, though. Have fun with your Bounty ;-) For the record: Google's docs on [Installing Optimize using analytics.js](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6262084) show the wrong order of statements in **Step 4**.

Answer (score 1):

This will occur If you have these three issues

1. You haven't tag your page to send hits to the `GA` property.
2. You have some kind of **Ad-blocking extension** or **tracking blocking extension** installed in your browser.
3. Try to **turn off your** antivirus software. Some times it cause to these kind of problems